# How to sort answers by date in Quora

Tags: quora

Is there a way to sort answers based on date in Quora? By default there is no such option to sort.

Answer (score 1):

No, not yet.

For more information you can visit these links:

[When is Quora going to feature sort by date?](https://www.quora.com/When-is-Quora-going-to-feature-sort-by-date)

[Is there any way that I can sort answers by date instead of by votes on Quora?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-that-I-can-sort-answers-by-date-instead-of-by-votes-on-Quora)

Comment: Thanks for response I tried Quora extender but it didn't help me .

Answer (score 1):

Though it is late, [Quora Quick Sort](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quora-quick-sort/baflgahbjendijbflolilmdpghedfadp) is a Chrome extension that enables you to sort by date. It also allows you to sort by upvotes, views, and comments.

For disclosure, I am the author of this plugin. I created this plugin due to facing the same issues as the poster when using Quora.

Update: The extension has been taken down by Google due to complaints from Quora for trade mark issues.

Comment: The link is broken now.

Comment: @MrReality although I would like to continue to update this extension, Google unfortunately took claims from the Quora team and have taken down the extension for trademark issues. I've tried removing all possible trademark related logos but the Google's unwilling to reinstate the extension unless the complainant authorizes. Unfortunately again, the complainant only left an email and have not replied to any of my emails since.